Adding Lines to text in Bulk
First of all, since English is not my native language, there may be spelling errors. I’m sorry for that.
Note: I'm using Windows PC
I have approximately 300 txt files. I want to add the line I want to the 1st line of each of these files. How can I do this in bulk to 300 files?
For example, I want to add the word “testfiles” to the 1st line of txt files
normal file content
test -host- teswordshere 1mayis.txt
test -host- teswordshere 1mayis.txt
test -host- teswordshere 1mayis.txt
test -host- teswordshere 1mayis.txt
test -host- teswordshere 1mayis.txt
test -host- teswordshere 1mayis.txt
the file content I want
testfiles
test -host- teswordshere 1mayis.txt
test -host- teswordshere 1mayis.txt
test -host- teswordshere 1mayis.txt
test -host- teswordshere 1mayis.txt
test -host- teswordshere 1mayis.txt
test -host- teswordshere 1mayis.txt
test -host- teswordshere 1mayis.txt
test -host- teswordshere 1mayis.txt
test -host- teswordshere 1mayis.txt
test -host- teswordshere 1mayis.txt
Additionally, as you can see in the example above, the txt files contain the text 1mayis.txt. I want to change this file name to the name of the file it is in.
For example
File name: deneme_007(228).txt
file content
test -host- teswordshere 1mayis.txt
test -host- teswordshere 1mayis.txt
test -host- teswordshere 1mayis.txt
the file content I want
test -host- teswordshere deneme_007(228).txt
test -host- teswordshere deneme_007(228).txt
test -host- teswordshere deneme_007(228).txt
Replace this part in each file with the original name of the file.
Is there a way to get this done?
I tried adding them one by one manually, but it takes hours to do it this way. Moreover, I have to do this process every 15 days.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
